# virtualenv pip can't install packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm having trouble installing packages using **virtualenv** with python. I do the following:

```
sudo virtualenv venv
cd venv/bin
source activate
pip install nose
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to execute /Users/../venv/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you create your virtualenv with sudo? That might be what's causing the problem. root owns the virtualenv and you try to install stuff in it as your regular user.

Comment: @gurka tired just now without the sudo and seeing the same error

Comment: What's your OS and what version of python are you running?

Comment: Sierra, python 2.7

Comment: If you didn't erase the virtualenv that you created with sudo, you're going to have problems using it without sudo as well. Never use sudo with virtualenv. Try `sudo rm -rf <broken venv dir>` and start over without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

**run:**

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ./pip install virtualenv
which virtualenv
```

This should point to **/usr/local/bin/virtualenv**

```
which pip
```

This should point to **/usr/local/bin/pip**

```
virtualenv /Users/yourname/path/to/env/envname
```